# Duplicate rows in SQL statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

the below SQL statement generates a pivot table, all of which is working correctly. However, at the bottom of the code, I am trying to display values from another table (availabilitynotes) - in this example below the note would be "A/P". Each single day will have either 0 or 1 notes on the individual day. When a note is present, the note is displayed. When no note is present, the COALESCE value is displayed. However, when a note for 1 teacher is set on a monday and one on a wednesday, a duplicate row is returned. How can I set it to return all values on one single row?

```
   WITH Bookings AS
(   SELECT  TeacherID,
            [WeekDay] = DATENAME(WEEKDAY, BookingDate),
            [Status] = CASE WHEN [2] > 0 THEN 'XXX'
                            WHEN [0] > 0 AND [1] > 0 THEN 'XXX'
                            WHEN [0] > 0 THEN 'PM'
                            WHEN [1] > 0 THEN 'AM'
                            WHEN [3] > 0 AND CONVERT(time(0), EndTime) <= CONVERT(time(0), '12:00:00') and CONVERT(time(0), StartTime) < CONVERT(time(0), '12:00:00') THEN 'PM'
                            WHEN [3] > 0 AND CONVERT(time(0), StartTime) >= CONVERT(time(0), '12:00:00') THEN 'AM'
                            WHEN [3] > 0 AND CONVERT(time(0), StartTime) <= CONVERT(time(0), '12:00:00') AND CONVERT(time(0), EndTime) >= CONVERT(time(0), '12:00:00') THEN 'XXX'
                        END

    FROM    (   SELECT  TeacherID, BookingDate, BookingDuration, StartTime, EndTime, [X] = 1
                FROM    BookingDays where (Status = 0 or Status IS NULL)
            ) BookingDays
            PIVOT
            (   SUM(X)
                FOR BookingDuration IN ([0], [1], [2], [3])
            ) pvt
             WHERE BookingDate >= DATEADD(ww, DATEDIFF(ww,0,@Date), 0) AND BookingDate <= DATEADD(ww, DATEDIFF(ww,0,@Date), 6)

), PivotedBookings AS
(   SELECT  *
    FROM    Bookings
            PIVOT
            (   MAX([Status])
                FOR [WeekDay] IN ([Monday], [Tuesday], [Wednesday], [Thursday], [Friday])
            ) pvt

)
SELECT  t.ID, 
        t.Firstname, 
        t.Surname, 
        CASE WHEN t.Nursery > 0 THEN 'NUR' WHEN t.Reception > 0 THEN 'REC' WHEN t.Year1 > 0 THEN 'Y1' WHEN t.Year2 > 0 THEN 'Y2' WHEN t.Year3 > 0 THEN 'Y3' WHEN t.Year4 > 0 THEN 'Y4' WHEN t.Year5 > 0 THEN 'Y5' WHEN t.Year6 > 0 THEN 'Y6' WHEN t.Year7 > 0 THEN 'Y7' WHEN t.Year8 > 0 THEN 'Y8' WHEN t.Year9 > 0 THEN 'Y9' WHEN t.Year10 > 0 THEN 'Y10' WHEN t.Year11 > 0 THEN 'Y11' WHEN t.ALevel > 0 THEN 'ALevel' END + ' - ' + CASE WHEN t.ALevel > 0 THEN 'ALevel' WHEN t.Year11 > 0 THEN 'Y11' WHEN t.Year10 > 0 THEN 'Y10' WHEN t.Year9 > 0 THEN 'Y9' WHEN t.Year8 > 0 THEN 'Y7' WHEN t.Year6 > 0 THEN 'Y6' WHEN t.Year5 > 0 THEN 'Y6' WHEN t.Year4 > 0 THEN 'Y4' WHEN t.Year3 > 0 THEN 'Y3' WHEN t.Year2 > 0 THEN 'Y2' WHEN t.Year1 > 0 THEN 'Y1' WHEN t.Reception > 0 THEN 'REC' WHEN t.Nursery > 0 THEN 'NUR' ELSE '' END as 'KeyStage',

        Monday = CASE WHEN an.Date = DATEADD(ww, DATEDIFF(ww,0,@Date), 0) AND an.TeacherID = t.ID THEN an.Text WHEN t.Status = 0 THEN 'XXX'  ELSE COALESCE(pb.Monday, '') END,
        Tuesday = CASE WHEN an.Date = DATEADD(ww, DATEDIFF(ww,0,@Date), 1) AND an.TeacherID = t.ID THEN an.Text WHEN t.Status = 0 THEN 'XXX'  ELSE COALESCE(pb.Tuesday, '') END,
        Wednesday = CASE WHEN an.Date = DATEADD(ww, DATEDIFF(ww,0,@Date), 2) AND an.TeacherID = t.ID THEN an.Text WHEN t.Status = 0 THEN 'XXX'  ELSE COALESCE(pb.Wednesday, '') END,
        Thursday = CASE WHEN an.Date = DATEADD(ww, DATEDIFF(ww,0,@Date), 3) AND an.TeacherID = t.ID THEN an.Text WHEN t.Status = 0 THEN 'XXX'  ELSE COALESCE(pb.Thursday, '') END,
        Friday = CASE WHEN an.Date = DATEADD(ww, DATEDIFF(ww,0,@Date), 4) AND an.TeacherID = t.ID THEN an.Text WHEN t.Status = 0 THEN 'XXX'  ELSE COALESCE(pb.Friday, '') END
FROM    Teachers t

        LEFT JOIN PivotedBookings pb
            ON pb.TeacherID = t.ID
        LEFT JOIN TeacherBands tb
            ON tb.ID = t.Band
        LEFT JOIN AvailabilityNotes an 
            ON t.ID = an.TeacherID
            WHERE t.Active = 0 and (t.Status = 1 or t.Status = 0) and t.PrimarySchool = 1
            ORDER BY t.Surname, t.Firstname asc
```

This generates the following output -

```
ID | Firstname | Surname | Mon | Tue | Wed | Thu | Fri 
1    Steve       Smith     XXX   PM    AM    A/P   NULL   
1    Steve       Smith     XXX   PM    AM    NULL   A/P
```

When I need it to be -

```
ID | Firstname | Surname | Mon | Tue | Wed | Thu | Fri 
1    Steve       Smith     XXX   PM    AM    A/P   A/P
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the valid value for each day, which will be greater than NULL if extant.

```
select   ID, Firstname, Surname
       , max(Monday) as Monday, -- etc
from ( your giant query ) as Q
group by ID, Firstname, Surname
```

should do the trick.